# How do I display the commit SHA1 as my application version in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I have a [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io) application and I'd like to display the application version as the Git commit SHA1, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [buildnumber-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) provides information about the current Git commit for the application as a maven property.

1. Make sure your `pom.xml` has it included and the `src/main/resources/application.properties` file is filtered by Maven, like the following:

```xml
 <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

2. Add the following to your `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
quarkus.application.version=${buildNumber}
```

The `buildNumber` property will be resolved and replaced during the maven build. The `quarkus.application.version` is a build-time property resolved during the Quarkus build (performed by the `quarkus-maven-plugin`).

If all steps were performed correctly, you should see an output as the following when running the application:

```sh
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2021-07-22 11:35:44,283 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.lic.VersionPrinter] (main) Flyway Community Edition 7.11.2 by Redgate
2021-07-22 11:35:44,284 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.dat.bas.BaseDatabaseType] (main) Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres (PostgreSQL 12.7)
2021-07-22 11:35:44,321 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbMigrate] (main) Current version of schema "public": 3
2021-07-22 11:35:44,322 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbMigrate] (main) Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2021-07-22 11:35:45,080 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-registry afd82c886d3d6fa60d1f29df642bf6565135ccef on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.1.0.Final) started in 2.327s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

HINT: you can resize the commit SHA by adding the `maven.buildNumber.shortRevisionLength`    Maven property to your pom.xml:

```xml
<maven.buildNumber.shortRevisionLength>7</maven.buildNumber.shortRevisionLength>
```